# Undo check out of subfolder in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

---

*How do I "un-checkout" a **subfolder** using TortoiseSVN?*

---

What have I tried:

- [Delete the entire subfolder](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=964069)
- [Export-in-place](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html), i.e. exporting the folder on top of itself
- Search SO for things like [undo+svn+checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SVN+undo+checkout)
- Peek inside the hidden `.svn` folders to see if I could manually edit things

The first two options seemed to work at first, but when I hit *Check for modifications* on the top-level folder it would tell me **the subfolder and its contents were "missing"**. This is of course not what I want.

To make things clearer, the relevant bit of my folder structure is similar to this:

```
//Repository/trunk/...
//Repository/branches
                     /some-feature-branch1/...
                     /some-feature-branch2/...
                     /some-feature-branch3/...
                     /some-feature-branch4/...
                     etc.
```

In the past I've done the following:

- Check out the `//Repository/branches` folder locally, without recursively grabbing the content.
- Made individual check-outs of some (but not all) feature branch subfolders

I'm trying to remove -say- `some-feature-branch3` from my local disk, but this always leads to status "missing" for the subfolder, when checking the "branches" folder for modifications.

Note that I'd prefer a way to fix this using *TortoiseSVN*, but if it isn't possible a command-line fix would be an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In SVN 1.7 you can do `svn up --set-depth exclude some-feature-branch3` (not sure if you can do it in SVN 1.6).

In Tortoise you can right click on `some-feature-branch3` -> 'Update to Revision' -> 'Update Depth: Exclude' -> 'Make Depth Sticky'.

If you can't do it in 1.6 you can do the same trick only with depth `empty`. It will leave the directory itself, but it will be empty which is enough for most practical purposes.

Answer (score 22):

Right click the folder and go to "Update to revision...".  In the dialog that pops up, set the Update Depth to "Exclude".  (Note, this only seems to work for folders.)  That will remove it from your working copy, but won't affect the repository.  Tortoise will just know not to try and update it during updates.

In order to undo it, you can right-click the parent folder (or its parent, and so on) and pick "Repo Browser".  Find the excluded folder, right-click and pick "Update item to revision".  You'll get that same dialog; this time, just make sure it says "Working copy".

Comment: A much better answer than the validated one in my opinion, doesn't leave any trace like an old folder, and is much easier